# Trying to fetch wp_nav_menu(); dynamically in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to fetch WordPress Menu dynamically like this image

[image]

i try this code. it shows result but not exactly what i want. i need exactly like image, in image i have Menu name ABOUT US and right below it has WHO WE ARE, i am stuck to call WHO WE ARE and also DROPDOWN help needed. THANKS

```
$defaults = array(
    'theme_location'  => '',
    'menu'            => '',
    'container'       => 'div',
    'container_class' => 'top-menu',
    'container_id'    => '',
    'menu_class'      => 'sf-menu sf-js-enabled',
    'menu_id'         => '',
    'echo'            => true,
    'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
    'before'          => '',
    'after'           => '',
    'link_before'     => '<span>',
    'link_after'      => '</span>',
    'items_wrap'      => '<ul class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
    'depth'           => 0,
    'walker'          => ''
);

wp_nav_menu( $defaults );

?>


<div class="top-menu">
                <ul class="sf-menu sf-js-enabled">
                    <li class="current_page_item sfHover"><a href="index.html">Home<span>Main Homepage</span></a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="aboutus.html">About Us<span>Who We Are</span></a>
                        <ul style="display: none; visibility: hidden;">
                            <li><a href="alternate.html" style="margin-left: 0px;">Alternate Homepage</a></li>
                            <li><a href="full_width.html" style="margin-left: 0px;">Full Width Page</a></li>
                            <li><a href="blog_single.html" style="margin-left: 0px;">Blog Single Page</a></li>                                                      
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class=""><a href="services.html">Services<span>What We do</span></a>
                        <ul style="display: none; visibility: hidden;">
                        <!-- start:drop down menu -->
                            <li><a href="#">Web Designing</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">HTML / CSS Coding</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Designing</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Graphics</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">SEO Marketing</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- end:drop down menu -->
                    </li>
                    <li class=""> <a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio<span>Our Works</span></a>
                        <ul style="display: none; visibility: hidden;">
                            <!--start:drop down menu -->
                            <li><a href="#">Websites</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Logos</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Prints</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- end:drop down menu -->
                    </li>
                    <li class=""> <a href="blog.html">Blog<span>Our Community</span></a>
                        <ul style="display: none; visibility: hidden;">
                            <li><a href="blog_single.html">Blog Single Page</a></li>                            
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class=""> <a href="contact.php">Contact Us<span>Location Info</span></a> </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: Did you try reading the codex? http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu

Comment: yes i read this but can't find any solution. if you provide me code i'll remain thankful to you. i am stuck to fetch two menus at a time like <a href="aboutus.html">About Us<span>Who We Are</span></a> i can fetch dropdown and menus but i don't have any idea how to fetch like that.

Comment: Just saw your question on CSS-Tricks. We need more info here and please show us how you're calling wp_nav_menu in your theme template. Are you saying that wp_nav_menu doesn't output the menu item's 'description'? If so you need to look at $item->description in a menu 'walker'. Here's a good thread on it: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14037/menu-items-description-custom-walker-for-wp-nav-menu

Comment: i add more info regarding question have a look please. thanks.